# Edit xml file using shell script / command

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I need to do this using unix script or command 
There is a xml file in /home/user/app/xmlfiles like

```
<book>
   <fiction type='a'>
      <author type=''></author>
   </fiction>
   <fiction type='b'>
      <author type=''></author>
   </fiction>
   <Romance>
       <author type=''></author>
   </Romance>
</book>
```

I want to edit author type in fiction as local .

```
   <fiction>
      <author type='Local'></author>
   </fiction>
```

I need to change the author type which is in **fiction tag  with attribute b** alone.
Please help  me with this using unix shell script or command. Thanks !

Comment: Why not use some text editor like vi / vim / emacs / gedit (pick any of your choice)? Or you can only use shell scripts and can't use any programs?

Comment: unfortunately i can use scritping only

Comment: I guess I'd recommend using xlst to transform the input into appropriate output, since that is the XMLish approach. you can perform XLST transformations in bash using `xlstproc` . http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/463/xslt-processor-command-line/

Comment: @FrankThomas  Take a look at my XMLish answer and please tell what you think about it.

Comment: @Darius  you still need the editor to understand XML.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just want to replace `<author type=''><\/author>` with `<author type='Local'><\/author>`, you can use that `sed` command:

```
sed "/<fiction type='a'>/,/<\/fiction>/ s/<author type=''><\/author>/<author type='Local'><\/author>/g;" file
```

But, when dealing with xml, I recommend an xml parser/editor like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u /book/*/author[@type]/@type -v "Local"  file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <fiction>
    <author type="Local"/>
  </fiction>
  <Romance>
    <author type="Local"/>
  </Romance>
</book>
```

Use the `-L` flag to edit the file inline, instead to printing the changes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24031/discussion-on-answer-by-chaos-edit-xml-file-using-shell-script-command).

Comment: Note that if your XML document has a default namespace (i.e. an `xmlns` attribute on the top-level tag), you'll need to [specify it to `xmlstarlet` as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030791/1175455).

Answer (score 16):

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "/book/fiction[@type='b']/author/@type" --value "Local" book.xml
```

Comment: A litte more explanatation and a link to the documentation would make your answer more helpful.

Comment: That does not really provide more info. It would be more helpful if you [edit]ed your post, used full sentences, and explained your one line of code.

Comment: `man xmlstarlet`

Comment: This answer is about as perfect as an answer can be, IMO!

Comment: I can't up-vote your answer more than one time, so this comment will have to suffice to express my gratitude: Thanks a million! Now I can update my CodeArtifact password in my maven settings.xml using a cronjob.

Answer (score 7):

We could use a xsl-document `doThis.xsl` and process the `source.xml` with `xsltproc` into a `newFile.xml`.

The xsl is based on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876382/using-xslt-to-copy-all-nodes-in-xml-with-support-for-special-cases).

Put this into a `doThis.xsl` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/> 

<!-- Copy the entire document    -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Copy a specific element     -->

<xsl:template match="/book/fiction[@type='b']/author">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

<!--    Do something with selected element  -->
            <xsl:attribute name="type">Local</xsl:attribute>

        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now we produce the `newFile.xml`

```
$:   xsltproc -o ./newFile.xml ./doThis.xsl ./source.xml
```

This will be the `newFile.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
   <fiction type="a">
      <author type=""/>
   </fiction>
   <fiction type="b">
      <author type="Local"/>
   </fiction>
   <Romance>
       <author type=""/>
   </Romance>
</book>
```

The expression used to find type b fiction is `XPath`.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy with `sed`. The following script will change the contents of file `a.xml` and will put the original to `a.bak` as a backup.

What it does is it searches each file for the string `<author type=''>` and replaces it with `<author type='Local'>`. The `/g` modifier means that it will try to make more than 1 replacement on each line if possible (not needed for your example file).

```
sed -i.bak "s/<author type=''>/<author type='Local'>/g" a.xml
```

Comment: I need to change the author type which is in fiction tag alone.Is that possible to check. I think above code will change all author tags.

Comment: Then you should have specified that in your question :) I see you edited the Q already... and also got better answer.